# Problem reading a matrix in a .txt file with fscanf

Tags: c, matrix

I have a problem with reading a txt file in my C code, the format of my txt file is :

```
10

5

1

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

With 10 being my number of columns (describe as dim.x in my code), 5 the number of rows (dim.y) and 1 the number of "2" in my matrix (which is not really important here).

my code to read this .txt file is

```
//CoupleInt contain just 2 int, x and y   
    CoupleInt dim;
    int nbrCible;
    FILE* fichier = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
    int items_lus = fscanf(fichier, "%d %d %d", &dim.x, &dim.y, &nbrCible);
//pre condtions in between ...
    int map[dim.x][dim.y];
    int compteurCible = 0;

    for(int y=0; y<dim.y; y++){
        for(int x=0; x<dim.x; x++){
            if(fscanf(fichier, "%d ", &map[y][x])!=1){
                printf("Stop");
                return 1;
            };
            if (map[y][x] == 2){
                compteurCible++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int y=0; y<dim.y; y++){
        for(int x=0; x<dim.x; x++){
            printf("%d ", map[y][x]);        
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fichier);
```

The first 3 numbers a read correctly and put into my variables but the matrix is not print correctly, it gives me this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 11 12 13 14 15
11 12 13 14 15 21 22 23 24 25
21 22 23 24 25 31 32 33 34 35
31 32 33 34 35 41 42 43 44 45
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

I'm working on Windows using minGW32 for compiling if it helps

I tried printing the numbers with a simple

```
While(fscanf(fichier, "%d", &test)==1){printf("%d",test)}
```

and it work perfectly printing all the numbers

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
```

Comment: `&map[y][x]` vs. `int map[dim.x][dim.y];` Hmmm.... You're code appears to variadic-declare your `map` dominant to `dim.x`, but indexes dominant on `dim.y`. I'd suspect that is likely related to your problem.

Comment: While a rose would smell as sweet by any other name, calling `rows` by the name `x` is what's known as a _code smell_. If you're thinking of them as `rows` then use a variable named `row`! KISS!! (Same advice for `cols`...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at these three lines in your code:

```c
int map[dim.x][dim.y];                       // x, y
if(fscanf(fichier, "%d ", &map[y][x])!=1){   // y, x
printf("%d ", map[y][x]);                    // y, x
```

This is your issue. You *create* an `NxM` matrix then *treat* it as if it's an `MxN` matrix. That's why it appears to work for the first five elements as they would be the same for both a `10x5` and `5x10` matrix.

---

By the way (and this isn't really related to your problem), I think the space in the `fscanf` format string is superfluous. The `%d` conversion specifier skips white space before starting to read its integer, and stops reading on the first character not forming *part* of that integer.

Comment: thx you I feel so dumb

Comment: Don't feel dumb, @yassine_deux_s, if you knew about even a *few* of the mistakes I (and probably everyone else) had made while learning, you feel a lot smarter :-)